# How can we get steady state result in jmeter html report?

Tags: jmeter, reporting

I am running test through command line and generating html report but it is giving complete test result (steady state and ramp up together).
Is there any way we can get only steady state data in jmeter non GUI mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider amending [`jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` and `jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date` properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general):

> - `start_date` - Start date of the range of data to use for report.
>   Date format is defined by date_format property.
>   Default: not filled which means data range will be used from the beginning
> - `end_date` - End date of the range of data to use for report.
>   Date format is defined by date_format property.
>   Default: not filled which means data range will be used until the end

The properties can be added to *user.properties* file or passed to JMeter startup script via `-J` command-line arguments, see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) article for more information.

Another option is using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) or [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) for removing the "unwanted" sample results from the .jtl result file prior to generating the dashboard.

And finally you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and conditionally call `prev.setIgnore()` function for all Samplers during the ramp-up phase.

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() < (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long + ctx.getThreadGroup().getPropertyAsLong('ThreadGroup.ramp_time') * 1000)) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```